# VSCode doesnt build and debug pthreads code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gdb, pthreads, vscode-debugger

I got a few codes from https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/ and I was trying to use the VSCode debugger to try to step through them but it doesnt seem to work.
Using tasks (ctrl+shift+B) I can build it just fine (I've added the -pthread flag) but when I try to debug it (F5) I get this error:

```
> Executing task: C/C++: gcc build active file <

Starting build...
Build finished with error:
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc5vG56K.o: in function `main':
/home/xristosp59/Documents/Programming/condvar.c:98: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/xristosp59/Documents/Programming/condvar.c:99: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/xristosp59/Documents/Programming/condvar.c:100: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/xristosp59/Documents/Programming/condvar.c:104: undefined reference to `pthread_join'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status 
The terminal process failed to launch (exit code: -1).
```

I've tried both -pthread and -lpthread flags in various places in my tasks.json but none seem to work, I always get this error.
Here is my current tasks.json: (this builds fine with tasks)

```json
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "-pthread",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/usr/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Generated task by Debugger"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

I'm on pop_os 20.10 if that matters.

Comment: Try linking explicitly with the `pthread` library (i.e. add the `-lpthread` argument).

Comment: as i said i also tried -lpthread, i retried it now just to make sure but i still get the same error

Comment: The order of libraries matters. Did you place the `-lpthread` option *last*?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes

Comment: Not only as last option, but also after the filename?

Comment: @Gerhardh yes, and for the life of me i cant find anything about this, ive been trying to make this work for 2+ hours now

Comment: What happens if you run the command in the shell? Is there something wrong with your gcc?

Comment: @Gerhardh 
```bash
xristosp59@pop-os:~/Documents/Programming$ gcc -pthread condvar.c
xristosp59@pop-os:~/Documents/Programming$ gcc condvar.c -lpthread
xristosp59@pop-os:~/Documents/Programming$ gcc -g -pthread condvar.c
xristosp59@pop-os:~/Documents/Programming$ gcc -g condvar.c -lpthread
```
they all seem to work

Comment: I am not fully familiar with VSCode. Do you have another set of rules for debugging?

Comment: @Gerhardh what do you mean? i think it uses the tasks.json file to build but other than that im not sure how this works either

Answer (score 3):

Ok so apparently vscode, when you first try to debug a c program, it creates a launch.json and tasks.json, the launch.json has a `"preLaunchTask": "C/C++: gcc build active file"` option and tasks.json has a `"label": "C/C++: gcc build active file"` option, which match, but I guess because `C/C++: gcc build active file` is already a task in vscode, it doesn't use the one in tasks (please correct me if I'm wrong). I changed the labels in both and now it works.

Comment: Adding "-pthread" to tasks.json only helped once I restarted VS Code.

Comment: @xristosp, what did you change exactly?